# UISearchDisplayController overlapping original table view

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a table view with a searchdisplayviewcontroller presented in a popoverviewcontroller in iOS 7...

[image: Search Disabled]

When the searchdisplay is active the results appear over the top of the original table view...

[image: Search Active]

How can I get the results to display correctly?

Now in iOS 6 it works perfectly, could it be a bug in iOS 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same issue. It probably is a bug.
Probably occurs only when display on popover.
See link below.

https://devforums.apple.com/message/888704

#### Workaround

```c
- (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller willShowSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}
```

Comment: Yup, I submitted it as a bug last week, Apple came back and verified it is a bug

Comment: Hi, Do you have that hyperlink to the bug?

Comment: So glad to have found this - was facing same issue. Thanks!